# Determine if a running Windows Service is functioning

Tags: windows, windows-services

Most of us have experienced a Windows service that has a status of "running" but is not doing what it is supposed to and we often restart the service.  I would like to know if there is a way to determine if a Windows service is "functioning"?  I don't mean it is "stopped", I mean how can I tell it is doing what it is supposed to in the "Running" state?

I found these previous questions below but these are oriented to developed Windows Service's and not a third party Windows Service installed with a software application or a core Windows Role\Feature service.  I know the logs may say "service has entered the stopped state" but if it is not "stopped" but also not functioning is there a way I can tell?

[How can I verify if a Windows Service is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178147/how-can-i-verify-if-a-windows-service-is-running)

[How do i know if my windows service is working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494197/how-do-i-know-if-my-windows-service-is-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending `SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE` with `ControlService` to the service should force the services control handler to process the event. If the service control handler thread is blocked this will fail.

Beyond that I don't know if there is a generic way to determine if a service is functioning correctly.

If you are looking at a specific known service, you might be able to try any TCP ports it is listening on or named pipes it creates. A web server should respond to a HEAD request for / for example.

Comment: Thanks.  yes, I thought a windows service not developed in-house would prove difficult.  I will try what you suggest